# Paypal custom field

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Now with Paypal we do not get to many custom fields and only one standard IPN receiving file, what means we have to split the Instant Payment Notification up to send to the applying website.

Now I was thinking to do this with the custom field.
Basically I post a custom value with the websitename and customer_id_number, what can by example look like this: 'website1 12345'.
Now to shift out the website name is easy as I can make multiple "if's" and "and if's" for that like:

```
if ($custom == 'website1%') {}
```

But now I of course want to shift out the customer_id_number, that is in this example 12345.
Typing by example something like:

```
$customer_id_number = somewaytoshiftthenumberout;
```

Is there a special technique of doing this and of so can you guys put me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `explode`.

Write for example website1||12345, and use :

```
$custom_exploded = explode('||', $custom);
if ($custom_exploded[0] == 'website1')
    // insert in DB $custom_exploded[1]
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I still do not know now how to get the customer ID number out except for doing if ($custom_exploded[0] == '00001-an endless number'). Or am I seeing it the wrong way?

Comment: With `explode` the customer ID is in `$custom_exploded[1]`.